# how to enable network service on ubuntu 19

Tags: ubuntu, networking, networkmanager

On the ubuntu 19 version, it is using NetworkManager instead of network service.
Because of which /etc/network/interfaces file is also empty.

But,it is mandatory for Openstack to use network service only.

Stopped and disabled NetworkManager using below commands.

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
systemctl disable NetworkManager
```

But, not able to start the network service using below command.

```
systemctl enable network
systemctl start network
```

Getting this error:

```
Failed to enable unit: Unit file network.service does not exist
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

To restart the network service use :`/etc/init. d/networking restart`

Comment: THank you, but getting this error.

/etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/networking: command not found

Comment: Seems this is working https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-switch-back-networking-to-etc-network-interfaces-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

But, still I can;t use systemctl start networl